# Mathf.Clamp для сравнения Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть ли какой нибудь аналог функции Mathf.Clamp для сравнения? 
Т.е. чтобы возвращало true если значение не больше заданного максимума и не меньше минимума. Аналог примерно вот такой писанины

```
if( ar.x > xmax && ar.x < xmin && ar.y > ymin && ar.y < ymax && ar.z > zmin && ..)
```

Как подобное записать покороче?

Comment: Вам нужно для скаляра (один компонент) или для вектора (2+ компонента сразу)?

Comment: [Mathf из UnityEngine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) не подходит?

Comment: @Kromster Я сравниваю Input.mouse position(Vector3) и Vector2, так что, видимо придется по одному компоненту сравнивать)

Comment: @eastwing Я упомянул его в посте. Объясните, как вы представляете его использование

Comment: Ок, неверно понял вопрос. Есть другая идея, сейчас опишу в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать метод-расширение для Vector3, для этого нужно объявить публичный метод внутри невложенного статического публичного класса. Примерно так:

```
public static class Extender
{
    public static bool Clamp (this Vector3 source, float[] Comparers)
    {
        return 
        source.x > Comparers[0] &&
        source.x < Comparers[1] &&
        source.y > Comparers[2] &&
        source.y < Comparers[3] &&
        source.z > Comparers[4] &&
        source.z < Comparers[5]
    }
}
```

Тогда непосредственно в обработчике запись ужмётся до:

```
if (ar.Clamp(new float[] {minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ}))
```

Пример грубый, можно сделать красивее и читаемее, но мысль иллюстрирует

[Подробнее о методах расширения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb383977.aspx)