# Преобразование класса в метод

Tags: c#, unity3d

В данный момент у меня есть внутренний класс. 
Можно ли его преобразовать в метод?

```
public class AreaExceptions : List<Rect>
{
public bool Contains(Vector3 point)
    {
    foreach(var item in this)
       {
        if (item.Contains(point) return true;
       }

    return false;
    }
}
```

Даже переформулирую вопрос. Вот код

```
List<Rect> Rects;

 public bool Contains(Vector3 point)
    {
    foreach(var item in Rects)
       {
        if (item.Contains(point) return true;
       }

    return false;
    }
```

Он будет выполнять ту же функцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [ответе про Clamp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586218/215964) я писал про методы расширения. Так же [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587726/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-c-unity3d) в комментариях упоминал, что можно расширить List. Насколько я помню, один класс, содержащий расширение, у вас уже есть. Можно добавить новый метод туда

```
public bool Contains(this List<Rect> source, Vector3 point)
{
foreach(var item in source)
   {
    if (item.Contains(point) return true;
   }

return false;
}
```

После чего, у любого экземпляра List(Rect) появится метод Contains, если ему будет виден класс с расширением